# How to set two values for one css property?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, alignment

I set a div style programicaly like below:

```
oDiv.Style.Add("text-align", "center");
```

it works in IE ,But not in FireFox,

for FireFox I must write this one:

```
oDiv.Style.Add("text-align", "-moz-center");
```

How could I have both?because if I write both ,just the second one works,
please help me.

Comment: Have you tried textAlign to see if it's a camel case issue?

Comment: I didnt get?could you please get me more explain 'MyStream'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks All.finally I could solved it with this :

```
.newClas{
   text-align: -moz-center;
   #text-align: center;
}
```

the # sign must be before next line in the css class

Answer (score 2):

Is the first CSS overwriten in you example? (I would think that ADD did overwrite, but I have not tested that). If so I would try doing this with pure CSS.
Create a CSS class with both CSS inside and then just change the CSS class of the oDiv to that class.

```
.newClas{
   text-align: -moz-center;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Class class like this:

```
oDiv.CssClass="newClass";
```

Comment: yes i think this should work and solve the problem, additionally it also reduces number of lines in server side code.

Comment: thanks for replay,but the result is the same.just the second one works.I mean the Dive in FF become Center but not IE .

Comment: In general terms, standard properties should be defined last.  @vesna, what do you get if you reverse the order above to -moz-center first and then center?

Comment: You are right MyStream, the standard should be last. I will switch in my example. Did you try that vesna?

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional style sheets to target only IE?

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Set the normal value in your default style sheet, then override in IE version.

Comment: I See your link It was great,but My problem steel exists,How could I use the link advise to solve my problem?

Comment: @vesna Look at Modernizr, this will help you greatly ;)